# NavBar in SiteDefinition

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, quicklaunch, site-definition

I have created a site definition for my project.
In this site definition I create two list instances of the same template by using the tag `<List>` of the site definition itself.

```
<Lists>
    <List Title="List1" Type="50001" Url="Lists/List1" FeatureId="{174CE875-9EF0-4C93-87E6-B33BDEB1899F}" />
    <List Title="List2" Type="50001" Url="Lists/List2" FeatureId="{174CE875-9EF0-4C93-87E6-B33BDEB1899F}" />
</Lists>
```

During site provision I setup different security for these lists. E.G. `List1` is only accessible from `Group 1` which has collaboration permissions while `List2` is only accessible from `Group 2` with collaboration permissions

I have then created a couple of links in the `NavBar` section of the site definition

```
<NavBars>
    <NavBar Name="Archives" Url="#" ID="1501">
        <NavBarLink Name="My Archive" Url="Lists/List1/AllItems.aspx"></NavBarLink>
        <NavBarLink Name="My Archive" Url="Lists/List2/AllItems.aspx"></NavBarLink>
    </NavBar>
</NavBars>
```

I expected that, depending on the connected user on of the two links would disappear but this is'nt true.
The links are always both visible, however one of the two, depending on the connected user, would generate an Acces Denied when clicked.

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you creating the lists via a feature? and trying to displ;ay on the left hand nav?

Comment: Right. I have a feature that deploys the List template and I am creating the List instance directly into the site definition. However I have tried to use `NavBarPage` instead of `NavBarLink` and everything works...